# how to enable slow_query_log in mysql for log the slow executed queries in mysql

Tags: mysql

how to enable slow_query_log in mysql for log the slow executed queries in mysql.I have added the following command in my configuration file like

```
log-slow-queries=D:/mysql/mysql-slow.log
```

here "D:/mysql" is the path where my queries will log and "mysql-slow.log" is the file name.

And after that i have restarted my server.but i didn't observe any action.Is there any problem  in my procedure.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your version, the relevant options could be [`slow_query_log_file`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_slow_query_log_file) and [`slow-query-log`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_slow_query_log) (the [`log-slow-queries`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-slow-queries) option has been deprecated since v5.1.29 and was removed in v5.6.1)

Whatever your version, you also need to adjust the values of [`long_query_time`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_long_query_time) and [`min_examined_row_limit`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_min_examined_row_limit)

Read also: [5.2.5. The Slow Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/slow-query-log.html)